# Grails watch files doesn't work inside Docker container running inside a Vagrant virtual machine

Tags: grails, filesystems, vagrant, docker

I have a fairly nested structure:

1. MacOSX workstation running a...
2. Vagrant VirtualBox virtual machine with `ubuntu/trusty64` running a...
3. Docker container running...
4. my application written in Grails

Every layer is configured in such a way as to share a portion of the file system from the layer above. This way:

- Vagrant, with `config.vm.synced_folder` directive in `Vagrantfile`
- Docker, with the `-v` command like switch and `VOLUME` directive in the `Dockerfile`

This way I can do development on my workstation and the Grails application at the bottom should (ideally) detect changes and recompile/reload on the fly. This is a feature that used to work when I was running the same application straight on the MacOSX, but now grails seems totally unaware of file changes. Of course, if I open the files with an editor (inside the Docker container) they are indeed changed and in fact if I stop/restart the grails app the new code is used.

I don't know how grails implements the watch strategy, but if it depends on some operating system level feature I suspect that file change notifications get lost somewhere in the chain.

Anyone has an idea of what could be the cause and/or how I could go about debugging this?

Comment: Have you tried modifying the file from inside the docker container and see if it reloads correctly?

Comment: Are you running in production or development mode on Docker?

Comment: @DavidC I'm not sure. How do see what mode am I running it?

Comment: If you are running in an IDE or on the command line as `grails runApp` then the default should be development mode and it should pick up file changes.  But if by any chance you are using production mode it will not but since you are unsure it seems likely you are in dev mode.

Comment: Like I specified, I run it inside a Docker container, so not inside an IDE. I run it with a simple `grails runApp`. Btw, my gut feeling tells me that the problem depends on the NFS share not propagating change events, like @roy-willemse pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to detect file changes (that I'm aware of):

**Polling**, which means checking timestamps of all files in a folder at a certain interval. Getting to "near instant" change detection requires very short intervals. This is CPU and disk intensive.

**OS Events** (inotify on Linux, FSEvents on OS X), where changes are detectable because file operations pass through the OS subsystems. This is easy on the CPU and disk.

Network File Systems (NFS) and the like don't generate events. Since file changes do not pass through the guest OS subsystem, the OS is not aware of changes; only the OS *making* the changes (OS X) knows about them.

Grails and many other File Watcher tools depend on FSEvents or inotify (or similar) events.

So what to do? It's not practical to 'broadcast' NFS changes from host to all guests under normal circumstances, considering the traffic that would potentially generate. However, I am of the opinion that VirtualBox shares should count as a special exception...

A mechanism to bridge this gap could involve a process that watches the host for changes and triggers a synchronization on the guest.

Check these articles for some interesting ideas and solutions, involving some type of rsync operation:

http://drunomics.com/en/blog/syncd-sync-changes-vagrant-box (Linux)
https://github.com/ggreer/fsevents-tools (OS X)

Rsync-ing to a non-NFS folder on your guest (Docker) instance has the additional advantage that I/O performance increases dramatically. VirtualBox shares are just painfully slow.

**Update!**

Here's what I did. First install **lsyncd** (OS X example, more info at http://kesar.es/tag/lsyncd/):

```
brew install lsyncd
```

Inside my Vagrant folder on my Mac, I created the file **lsyncd.lua**:

```
settings {
    logfile = "./lsyncd.log",
    statusFile = "./lsyncd.status",
    nodaemon = true,
    pidfile = "./lsyncd.pid",
    inotifyMode = "CloseWrite or Modify",
}

sync {
    default.rsync,
    delay = 2,
    source = "./demo",
    target = "vagrant@localhost:~/demo",
    rsync = {
        binary   = "/usr/bin/rsync",
        protect_args = false,
        archive = true,
        compress = false,
        whole_file = false,
        rsh = "/usr/bin/ssh -p 2222 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no"
    },
}
```

What this does, is sync the folder `demo` inside my Vagrant folder to the guest OS in `/home/vagrant/demo`. Note that you need to set up login with SSH keys to make this process frictionless.

Then, with the vagrant VM running, I kicked off the lsyncd process. The `-log Exec` is optional; it logs its activity to the stdout:

```
sudo lsyncd lsyncd.lua -log Exec
```

On the vagrant VM I started Grails (2.4.4) in my synced folder:

```
cd /home/vagrant/demo
grails -reloading run-app
```

Back on my Mac in IntelliJ I edited a Controller class. It nearly immediately triggered lsyncd (2 sec delay) and quickly after that I confirmed Grails recompiled the class!

To summarize:

- Edit your project files on your Mac, execute on your VM
- Use lsyncd to rsync your changes to a folder inside your VM
- Grails notices the changes and triggers a reload
- Much faster disk performance by not using VirtualBox share

**Issues:** Textmate triggers a type of FSEvent that lsyncd does not (yet) recognize, so changes are not detected. Vim and IntelliJ were fine, though.

Hope this helps someone! Took me a day to figure this stuff out.

Comment: I am running a grails app via docker which recompiles fine with Atom/TextEdit/Sublime but does not work(plus breaks recompiling) if changes made with IntelliJ. How would I change the .lua file if I were to run directly through Docker(not on Vagrant) but be able to make changes through IntelliJ??

Answer (score 1):

The best way I have found to have filesystem notifications visible within the container was as follows:

1. Create two folders, one to map the project and a "mirror"
2. Map the project in the first folder
3. Keep a background script running in the container, rsyncing the project folder  to "mirror"
4. Run the project from "mirror"

It may not be the most efficient or most elegant way, but this way was transparent to users of the container. No additional script needs to be run.

Not tested in a larger project, but in my case I did not realize performance issues.

https://github.com/altieres/docker-jekyll-s3

Answer (score 0):

Vagrant already includes some options for rsync, so it's not necessary to install a special program on the host machine.

In Vagrantfile, I configured rsync:

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "rsync",  rsync__exclude: [ "./build", ".git/" ]
```

Then on command line (in host), I run:

```
vagrant rsync
```

Which performs a single synchronization from host to guest.

or

```
vagrant rsync-auto
```

Which runs automatically when changes on host are detected.

See more at [Vagrant rsync Documentation](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/rsync.html) and [rsync-auto](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/rsync-auto)