# Hot Swap or hot deploy with docker and grails 4

Tags: java, docker, gradle, grails, hotswap

sorry to bother the community. I am upgrading fro Grails 2.4.5 to Grails 4.0.1. I have dockerized Grails, Gradle, Java with a base image of Ubuntu and the following versions:

- OS: Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise
- Grails Version:4.0.1
- Gradle Version:5.6.3
- Docker Desktop Version: 2.1.0.5
- Docker Engine version: 19.03.5
- Java Version: openjdk version "1.8.0_222"

I am using docker Desktop for Windows (I have no choice). I run the application from inside the container with the command: `grails -Dgrails.env=docker run-app -reloading`. I don't want to re-run the application every time i make a change in the code. I want to use the feature "Hot Deploy or Hot Swap" and whenever i make a change it gets deployed in the application automatically.
I have researched through out all the web without any successful result. Does anyone can help me with this issue i am having, it is making my development time increase because of this. Any information you need to help me please don't hesitate to ask.
Thanks in advance

Comment: are you developing in docker? why not develop in windows and deploy to docker (you would never have reloading on or run via run-app for production)

Comment: no, i'm running the grails application in the container but i develop in my local environment. When ever i make a change locally, i have to re-run the application inside the container. What I want is not the re-run the application again in the container

Comment: You ran into a problem similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26406130/8482479). Grails use file notifications events which don't work with Docker Desktop. See [inotify on shared drives does not work](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/troubleshoot/#inotify-on-shared-drives-does-not-work). One way to work around this limitation is to use polling and force the events when something changed (e.g. touch files). Another possible solution as suggested in the post mentioned above is to have two directories kept in sync.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers, i am going to try every possible answer you gave me and i will tell you how it went.

Comment: Again thank you for your answers, but they didn't solve the problem. We are still investigating the issue, as soon as we find out the solution i am going to post it on here. T

Comment: One possible problem could be that you don't have mapped your source code as a volume. That way every time you change the code the image doesn't know about it. I would rather use a docker-compose file to run the dev environment. Take a look at this setup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65431299/how-do-i-install-grails-in-a-docker-image/65431834#65431834